# How to disable action on horizontal swipe in viewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

New activity opens when you tap on card (see image) but If you swipe horizontally(by mistake or knowingly) same thing happens which should be disabled. How to do that?

I'm using nested `viewPager`. First one is horizontal viewPager(in this horizontal scroll is disabled) as you can see and in the first fragment(named Digest), I've used vertical viewPager and it is working fine. The problem is if I try to scroll horizontally, Next `Activity` opens(which should open on click of the card). I want that nothing should happen if I scroll horizontally over the card.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You´re not being clear in your question so ill assume you want to block viewpager swipe entirely.

You only need to extend the viewpager widget like this.

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

  private boolean isPagingEnabled = true;

  public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
      super(context);
  }

  public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
  }

  public void setPagingEnabled(boolean b) {
      this.isPagingEnabled = b;
  }
```

}

Then use this new version for your horizontal viewpager and setPagingEnabled(false) programatically. Be careful, you are still able to interact with the viewpager through tabs, it only blocks the swipe event.

Comment: Think his question is that a new activity opens on horizontal and diagonal swipe on card but he only wants it to open on tap on card... In other words his page has vertical scroll but as the card is big and our thumb usually works diagonally it opens the card page(new activity) instead of scrolling up.

Comment: Something like this but he has vertical scroll on view pager...  http://queforum.com/android-applications/167786-android-how-make-viewpager-swipe-diagonal-swipes.html